# React-native: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

Tags: android, windows, powershell, react-native, npx

I have did my React-native setup following instructions from https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

*Project has been created successfully.*

Android phone also connected using USB but when I try to install App on phone using command-

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Following error occured and BUILD FAILED

`what went wrong`

`Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache`

Error:

```
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
```

I'm using **Powershell** to perform commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was very simple I got it after about a week of posting this question.

You just need to update to latest gradle version.

1. Go to ***android > gradle > gradle-wrapper.properties*** file in your project folder.

In ***gradle-wrapper.properties*** file change the following line with [latest version](https://gradle.org/releases/) of gradle:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

2. Just change the version number 6.7.1 to the latest number.

Run command again to build your app:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

It resolved my problem and React-native app got installed on android phone using USB.